# Android application dev using the SDK or HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: android, web-applications

Last night I learnt that it is possible to develop apps for Android using HTML, CSS and JavaScript, much like you would do a client side website. Is this a widely used approach? Because I have started to learn developing with the SDK but I naturally know more about HTML, CSS and Javascript, so I'd like to leverage that knowledge if possible.

So basically my question boils down to this: Are Android web apps as good as native apps? Can the same functionality be achieved through web apps?

Regards
Renault

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.phonegap.com/start/#android 
PhoneGap is based Web Technologies HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
It's very simple to use it. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

While other HTML/Css/JS frameworks run your apps inside a web-browser-like environment, Appcelerator claims to run your apps natively. And it seems (almost?) all the functionality that can be achieved through native apps can also be achieved through their SDK.

They also have several convenience features like directly running the app on an emulator or a device, packaging the app for deployment etc., and Titanium Developer runs on Windows, Linux and OS X.